# maintain url in codeigniter for pages,categories,subcategories and product?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to do URL format likes below

for pages -

www.example.com/page-name
for categories

www.example.com/category-name/sub-category-name
for product

www.example.com/category-name/sub-category-name/product-name

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: i need url category/subcategory/productname...for ex: www.example.com/category-name/sub-category-name/product-name this format. bro. U have any examples???

Comment: i am trying this format url project..but all products view in single product view...

Comment: define in route.php [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: example.com/product/1/ this format url is works fine bro...but i need category/subcategory/subsubcategory... for example: Mobile/Samsung/Samsung S8....i need this format url...bro...???

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem if you are using only one controller i.e. your default controller. Say your default controller is called "Home". Then you can simply do this.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Home_model');
     }
    public function _remap()
    {
        $category = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $sub_category = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $product = $this->uri->segment(4);
// Check what you have 
 // echo $category.'_'. $sub_category.'_'. $product; 

        if($category == '' || $sub_category == '' || $product == '')
      {
        //send user to landing page of website
         $this->load->view('landing');
      }
      else
      {
        // get the product details
        $render['product_details] = $this->Home_model->get_product_details($category, $sub_category, $product);
         // send product details to view
        $this->load->view('product_details', $render);
      }
    }
}
```